# Cannot read property 'send' of undefined in welcomeChannel.send

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```js
bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {
    console.log(member)
    const welcomeChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === 'welcome');
    //const channelId = '789052445485563935' // welcome channel
    const message = `Welcome <@${member.id}> to the server!`
    const message2 = 'Please check the rules before accessing the rest of the server!'
    welcomeChannel.send(message);
 
})
```

I get the error in `welcomeChannel.send`. It won't send the message and crashes the bot. I am looking for anyone who can help me solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have a channel named "welcome"? Because it can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the channel isn't in the cache yet. If you know the channel id try using `member.guild.channels.resolve(channelId)`

Comment: Can you mark it as the answer, will let other people know that it worked